# TKINTER ENTRY : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' tkinter entry cant get value in a frame

Tags: python, tkinter, get, attributeerror, tkinter-entry

i used functions and tk frames / entry and i cant seem to get the value of the entry

i used a frame to put all my widgets. i cant seem to get the value of all my tk entry.

i want to be able to get the value, store it in the file same as the date and time and then be able to retrieve and print it as a label.

here's a snippet in my codes:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import uuid
import json
from pyglet import font
from tkcalendar import *
from datetime import *
from tktimepicker import SpinTimePickerModern
from tktimepicker import constants

#tk.resizable(height = None, width = None)

# set colours
bg_colour = "#141414"

# load custom fonts
font.add_file("fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf")
font_bold = font.load('Quicksand', bold=True)

font.add_file("fonts/Quicksand-Regular.ttf")
font_reg = font.load('Quicksand', bold=False)

def clear_widgets(frame):
    # select all frame widgets and delete them
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()


def close():
   #win.destroy()
   root.quit()

        
def load_frame1():
    clear_widgets(frame2)
    # stack frame 1 above frame 2
    frame1.tkraise()
    # prevent widgets from modifying the frame
    frame1.pack_propagate(False)

    # create logo widget
    img = Image.open("assets/logo_mc.png")
    logo_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    logo_widget = tk.Label(frame1, image=logo_img, bg=bg_colour)
    logo_widget.image = logo_img
    logo_widget.pack(pady=30)

    #img = tk.PhotoImage(file="assets/logo_mc.png")
    #w = tk.Label(frame1, image=img)
    #w.pack(pady=30)


    # create label widget for instructions
    tk.Label(
        frame1, 
        text="Be the MADDEST web developer ever!",
        bg=bg_colour,
        fg="#7d6dbb",
        font=(font_bold, 17)
        ).pack(pady=10)
    tk.Label(
        frame1, 
        text="Ready for an interview?",
        bg=bg_colour,
        fg="#7d6dbb",
        font=(font_reg, 15)
        ).pack()
    
    # create button widget 2
    tk.Button(
        frame1,
        text="SET AN APPOINTMENT NOW",
        font=(font_reg, 15),
        bg="#7d6dbb",
        fg="white",
        cursor="hand2",
        activebackground="#83d2c9",
        activeforeground="#141414",
        command=lambda:load_f2()
        ).pack(pady=30)

def load_f2():  
    clear_widgets(frame1)
    # stack frame 1 above frame 2
    frame2.tkraise()
    # prevent widgets from modifying the frame
    frame2.pack_propagate(True)


    def get_entry():
        print(e_name.get())
        print(e_email.get())
        print(e_age.get())
        print(e_city.get())
        print(e_num.get())
        #f = open("saved app.txt",'a')
        #f.write("Date: " + selected_date +  "\nTime: " + selected_time)
        #f.close()

    def save_app():
        answer = messagebox.askquestion(title='Checking...', message='Are you sure with your chosen date and time?')
        if (answer == 'yes'):
            check_date = cal.get_date()
            convert_datetime = datetime.strptime(check_date, '%m/%d/%y')

            while True:
                if((convert_datetime.weekday() == 5) or (convert_datetime.weekday() == 6)):
                    #error, wont continue
                    messagebox.showerror(title='Error!', message='We only work on weekdays! Kindly select a date accordingly.')
                    break
                else:
                    get_entry()
                    selected_time = cb_time.get()
                    selected_date = check_date

                    f = open("saved app.txt",'a')
                    f.write("Date: " + selected_date +  "\nTime: " + selected_time)
                    f.close()

                    messagebox.showinfo("Saved", "Appointment saved successfully!")
                    break
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo(title='Try again', message='Choose your appointment wisely!')

    def print_app():
        p = tk.Tk()
        p.geometry('400x500')
        p.title('Print Appointment')
        p.resizable(False, False)

        r = open("saved app.txt", "r")
        results = r.readlines()
        

        l2 = tk.Label(
                p, 
                text="Kindly Screenshot this information.",
                font=("font_reg", 10)
                )
        l2.pack()

        tk.Label(p, text=str(results)).pack()

    tk.Label(
        frame2, 
        text="SET YOUR APPOINTMENT",
        bg=bg_colour,
        fg="#8675CD",
        font=("font_reg", 16)
        ).place(x=500, y=30)
    tk.Label(
        frame2, 
        text="Enter your details.",
        bg=bg_colour,
        fg="white",
        font=("font_reg", 10)
        ).place(x=350, y=85)
    tk.Label(
        frame2, 
        text="Name: ",
        bg=bg_colour,
        fg="white",
        font=("font_reg", 10)
        ).place(x=350, y=120)
    e_name = tk.Entry(
        frame2,
        bg="#d6d7ed",
        textvariable=e_name
        ).place(x=430, y=120)
    tk.Label(
        frame2, 
        text="Email: ",
        bg=bg_colour,
        fg="white",
        font=("font_reg", 10)
        ).place(x=350, y=150)
    e_email = tk.Entry(
        frame2,
        bg="#d6d7ed",
        textvariable=e_email
        ).place(x=430, y=150)
    tk.Label(
        frame2, 
        text="Age: ",
        bg=bg_colour,
        fg="white",
        font=("font_reg", 10)
        ).place(x=350, y=180)
    e_age = tk.Entry(
        frame2,
        bg="#d6d7ed",
        textvariable=e_age
        ).place(x=430, y=180)
    tk.Label(
        frame2, 
        text="City: ",
        bg=bg_colour,
        fg="white",
        font=("font_reg", 10)
        ).place(x=350, y=210)
    e_city = tk.Entry(
        frame2,
        bg="#d6d7ed",
        textvariable=e_city
        ).place(x=430, y=210)
    tk.Label(
        frame2, 
        text="Phone No.: ",
        bg=bg_colour,
        fg="white",
        font=("font_reg", 10)
        ).place(x=350, y=240)
    e_num = tk.Entry(
        frame2,
        bg="#d6d7ed",
        textvariable=e_num
        ).place(x=430, y=240)

    #cal_f = LabelFrame(frame2,text="Select a date.", foreground="white", bg=bg_colour)
    #cal_f.place(x=550, y=100)

    #style = ttk.Style(frame2)
    #style.theme_use('clam')

    tk.Label(
        frame2, 
        text="Select a date.",
        bg=bg_colour,
        fg="white",
        font=("font_reg", 10)
        ).place(x=700, y=85)

    cal = Calendar(frame2, selectmode="day", background="#404040", disabledbackground="#gray", bordercolor="#d6d7ed", 
               headersbackground="#7d6dbb", normalbackground="#2e2d2d", foreground='#d6d7ed', 
               normalforeground='#d6d7ed', headersforeground='#d6d7ed')
    cal.place(x=700, y=110)

    #time_picker = AnalogPicker(frame2)
    #time_picker.pack()

    #theme = AnalogThemes(time_picker)
    #theme.setDracula()

    tk.Label(
        frame2, 
        text="Select a time.",
        bg=bg_colour,
        fg="white",
        font=("font_reg", 10)
        ).place(x=700, y=320)
    
    # define the style for combobox widget
    style= ttk.Style()
    style.theme_use('clam')
    style.configure("TCombobox", fieldbackground= "#7d6dbb", background= "white")
    
    n = tk.StringVar()
    cb_time = ttk.Combobox(frame2, width = 20, textvariable = n, text="8:00 A.M.", state='readonly') 

    # adding combobox drop down list
    cb_time['values'] = ("8:00 A.M.",
                          "9:00 A.M.",
                          "10:00 A.M.",
                          "11:00 A.M.",
                          "13:00 P.M.",
                          "14:00 P.M.",
                          "15:00 P.M.",
                          "16:00 P.M.",
                          "17:00 P.M.",)
    cb_time.place(x=700, y=350)
    cb_time.set("8:00 A.M.")

    tk.Button(
        frame2,
        text="SAVE",
        font=(font_reg, 10),
        bg="#7d6dbb",
        fg="white",
        cursor="hand2",
        activebackground="#83d2c9",
        activeforeground="#141414",
        command=lambda:save_app()
        ).place(x=555, y=450)
    tk.Button(
        frame2,
        text="PRINT",
        font=(font_reg, 10),
        bg="#7d6dbb",
        fg="white",
        cursor="hand2",
        activebackground="#83d2c9",
        activeforeground="#141414",
        command=lambda:print_app()
        ).place(x=610, y=450)
    tk.Button(
        frame2,
        text="BACK",
        font=(font_reg, 10),
        bg="#7d6dbb",
        fg="white",
        cursor="hand2",
        activebackground="#83d2c9",
        activeforeground="#141414",
        command=lambda:load_frame1()
        ).place(x=666, y=450)
    tk.Button(
        frame2,
        text="DONE",
        font=(font_reg, 10),
        bg="#7d6dbb",
        fg="white",
        cursor="hand2",
        activebackground="#83d2c9",
        activeforeground="#141414",
        command=lambda:close()
        ).place(x=720, y=450)
    
    




        
    
# initiallize app with basic settings
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Madcat Agency | Hiring Now")
root.resizable(False, False)
 
# create a frame widgets
frame1 = tk.Frame(root, width=1250, height=690, bg=bg_colour)
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg=bg_colour)
frame3 = tk.Frame(root, bg=bg_colour)

# place frame widgets in window
for frame in (frame1, frame2):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nesw")

# load the first frame
load_frame1()


# run app
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a callback function ...

```
    def get_entry():
        print(e_name.get())
        print(e_email.get())
        print(e_age.get())
        print(e_city.get())
        print(e_num.get())
```

that is trying to `get()` from a bunch of variables that are `None`. The variables `e_name`, `e_mail` `e_num` and `e_age` are all `NoneType` and therefore do not have a `get` method.

The reason all of those variables are `None` is because that is what the  `.place()` method returns which you are calling on the lines where you declare those variables.

```
    e_name = tk.Entry(
        frame2,
        bg="#d6d7ed",
        textvariable=e_name
        ).place(x=430, y=120)
    ...
    e_email = tk.Entry(
        frame2,
        bg="#d6d7ed",
        textvariable=e_email
        ).place(x=430, y=150)
    ...
    e_age = tk.Entry(
        frame2,
        bg="#d6d7ed",
        textvariable=e_age
        ).place(x=430, y=180)
    ...
    e_city = tk.Entry(
        frame2,
        bg="#d6d7ed",
        textvariable=e_city
        ).place(x=430, y=210)
    ...
    e_num = tk.Entry(
        frame2,
        bg="#d6d7ed",
        textvariable=e_num
        ).place(x=430, y=240)
```

You are also referencing a variable before it has been defined which would also raise an exception.

What you can do is split each of the declarations above into smaller individual operations.

For example:

```
    e_name = StringVar()
    e_email = StringVar()
    e_age = StringVar()
    e_city = StringVar()
    e_num = StringVar()

    e_name_entry = tk.Entry(frame2, bg="#d6d7ed", textvariable=e_name)
    e_email_entry = tk.Entry(frame2,bg="#d6d7ed", textvariable=e_email)
    e_age_entry = tk.Entry(frame2,bg="#d6d7ed", textvariable=e_age)
    e_city_entry = tk.Entry(frame2, bg="#d6d7ed", textvariable=e_city)
    e_num_entry = tk.Entry(frame2, bg="#d6d7ed", textvariable=e_num)

    e_name_entry.place(x=430, y=120)
    e_email_entry.place(x=430, y=150)
    e_age_entry.place(x=430, y=180)
    e_city_entry.place(x=430, y=210)
    e_num_entry.place(x=430, y=240)
```